# Android picture in background

Tags: android, image, android-layout

Hi, I have no clue how to go about this but I want to put in the background of all the screens a picture instead of it being black. How would I do this through XML or the Java code and what kind of layout would I have to use if it is in XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `android:background="@drawable/your_image"`to the root layout of your XML.
It will be stretched to fill all the screen, so if your image doesn't perfectly match the screen size you'll need to create another BitmapDrawable XML in which you declare the properties of the image.

Comment: ok is this done at the bottom of this part by u mean the root?

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/base"
    >

Comment: and then where do i have to store that image in the res folder?

Comment: @user998056 Use a LinearLayout with background
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/base" android:background="@drawable/your_image">
and store your image in any drawable folder of your project (which is in res folder)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following attribute on some `ViewGroup` layout objects (like `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`):

```
android:background="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE_RESOURCE_HERE"
```

Make sure to set your `layout_height` and `layout_width` to `fill_parent` on the root `View` and set this attribute on it if you want the background to fill the screen.

Comment: and then where does the image get stored in the res folder?

Comment: You need to put the image as a .png in your drawable folder... don't include the .png in the @drawable/yourImg assuming your image is called yourImg.png

Comment: The drawable folder is in res/drawable.  You need to use resource qualifiers if your image doesn't scale well.  Read about that here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

Answer (score 0):

First you would create a style with the background set to your image. Then you would use the `android:theme` attribute on your application to apply the style to all the activities in your application. For more information, please read [Style and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).